# C#.NET form not displaying properly in C++/CLI

Tags: c#, winforms, c++-cli, command-line-interface

I am trying to get to grips with calling C# classes from C++ using a CLI Wrapper.  I think I'm almost there, but my form isn't displaying properly. Although I suspect this might be something to do with it having its own thread, I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing, and therefore what I'm doing WRONG.  Hopefully you guys can shed some light on it for me.

Here's the form (very uninteresting): https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWg51.png

**TestForm.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ManagedForms
{
    public partial class TestForm : Form
    {
        public TestForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void TestForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void changeLabel()
        {
            this.label1.Text = "Now I have new text!!";
        }

    }
}
```

**ManagedFormsCLIWrapper.h**

```
class TestFormWrapperPrivate;

class TestFormWrapper
{
private: 
    TestFormWrapperPrivate* _private;

public: 
    TestFormWrapper();
    ~TestFormWrapper();

    void ShowForm();
    void ChangeLabel();

};
```

**ManagedFormsCLIWrapper.cpp**

```
#using "..\ManagedForms\bin\Debug\ManagedForms.dll"
#using <System.Windows.Forms.dll>
#using <System.dll>

#include <msclr\auto_gcroot.h>

using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

class TestFormWrapperPrivate
{
public: msclr::auto_gcroot<ManagedForms::TestForm^> testForm;
};



class __declspec(dllexport) TestFormWrapper
{
private:
    TestFormWrapperPrivate* _private;

public:
    TestFormWrapper()
    {
        _private = new TestFormWrapperPrivate();
        _private->testForm = gcnew ManagedForms::TestForm();
    }

    ~TestFormWrapper()
    {
        delete _private;
    }

    void ShowForm()
    {
        _private->testForm->Show();
    }

    void ChangeLabel()
    {
        _private->testForm->changeLabel();
    }   

};
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "ManagedFormsCLIWrapper.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int  fred;
    TestFormWrapper testForm;


    testForm.ShowForm();

    std::cin >> fred;  // to allow me to see the form before and after label change

    testForm.ChangeLabel(); 

    std::cin >> fred;  // to allow me to see the form before and after label change

    return 0;

}
```

The files exist within three projects in my solution:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rERQW.png

And execution does successfully launch the form, but something's up: the label is missing.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MPDj.png

Entering something into the console to progress to the label rewrite kinda works: the white area has changed size:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Os2w.png

However, the contents don't show, and mouseover changes the pointer to everyone's favorite 'thinking' pointer.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Any window always needs a message loop. You never call `Application.Run` to run a message loop so your window never paints itself. It would do the same thing straight from C#

Comment: @Dark does that mean I can only use this technique to access non-UI classes from my managed libraries, or is there a way to get the forms working too?

Comment: Yes, it can work. You need to call `Application.Run` somewhere in the same thread that called `Show` on the form.

Comment: @DarkFalcon like this?  void ShowForm()
 {
  Application.Run();
  _private->testForm->Show();
  _private->testForm->Refresh();
 }.  Doesn't seem to work, as that function is C++

Comment: I feel I'm almost there with this:  void ShowForm()
 {
  System::Windows::Forms::Application::Run((System::Windows::Forms::Form)*_private->testForm);
 }

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work:

```
void ShowForm()
{
    _private->testForm->Show();
    _private->testForm->Refresh();
}

void ChangeLabel()
{
    _private->testForm->changeLabel();
    _private->testForm->Refresh();
}
```

Comment: On further examination, this does NOT work. Sure, the form updates, but it's still pretty much hung. Cannot close or reposition, and it still has our friend the 'thinking' pointer on mouseover.